# HTTP Post returns the whole website html instead of a JSON response

Tags: c#, json, post

So im trying to get a JSON response from a server using [this](https://soruly.github.io/whatanime.ga/#/) api
The problem is that it returns the html code of the [homepage](http://www.whatanime.ga) of the website. If you look at the api page it says that it should return some json. 
I think there's something wrong with my code.

Any suggestions?

The image im using: [image: anime picture]

My code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
        String base64 = ImageToBase64(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.whatanime.ga/api/search?token=<token>");

        var postData = base64;
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("data:" + responseString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually its important what `http://www.whatanime.ga/api/search?token=<token>` returns

Comment: Look at the api page, its too long to post here. but it should return a error 403 if the token is invalid and a error 401 if the token is invalid.

Comment: well what if the token is valid, what it returns?

Comment: [example](https://soruly.github.io/whatanime.ga/#/?id=search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after some messing with other options I've found a working (for me) solution 
I'm posting this to help people in the future with the same problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
        String base64 = ImageToBase64(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["image"] = base64;
            var response = client.UploadValues("https://whatanime.ga/api/search?token=<token>", values);
            var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            Console.WriteLine("data: " + responseString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I read in documentation

```
POST /api/search?token={your_api_token} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: whatanime.ga

image={Base64 Encoded Image}
```

you have to provide key pairs value to provide image

something like this

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    response = client.UploadValues("http://www.whatanime.ga/api/search?token=<token>", 
        new NameValueCollection() {{ "image", base64 }
    });
}
```

end read response state

```
Returns HTTP 403 if API token is invalid.

Returns HTTP 401 if API token is missing.   

Note that there is a hard limit of 1MB post size. You should ensure your Base64 encoded image is < 1MB. Otherwise the server responds with HTTP 413 (Request Entity Too Large).
```